# Export every entry for a given identifier to an excel workbook by that identifier

Tags: ms-access, vba, export, excel-2010, unique

I have a database containing over 4,000,000 intra-operative temperature readings (4354499 x 8). The database is therefore too large to copy and paste.

Variables:

**caseID** - the unique identifier for the surgical case. If one patient has multiple surgeries on different days, there will be a different caseID for each surgery

**temperature** - the temperature value

**time** - the time at which the temperature was recorded

The temperature readings are taken every 15 seconds throughout surgery, so a case having over 500 temperature readings is the norm. Each surgical case has its own unique identifier (caseID), but the caseID will be the same for all 500 readings.

What I need is an automated method for extracting the temperature readings for each case. It could be in any of the following formats:

- 1 Excel workbook containing multiple worksheets, with each worksheet containing all the temperature readings pertaining to one caseID. This may not work if Excel limits the number of worksheets in a workbook.
- Many Excel workbooks, each containing the temperature readings of one caseID (probably preferred, since I don't mind having tons of files)

Comment: Check out Transferspreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

In its most rudimentary form, what you're looking for is some VBA code like this:

```
Public Function DumpTempsByCaseToExcel() As Boolean
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Const OutPath = "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\"
Const DataTableName = "Temperatures"
Const TempQueryDefName = "zzzTempQuery"

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT caseID FROM [" & DataTableName & "]", dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    On Error Resume Next
    cdb.QueryDefs.Delete TempQueryDefName
    On Error GoTo DumpTempsByCaseToExcel_Error
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef(TempQueryDefName, "SELECT * FROM [" & DataTableName & "] WHERE caseID=""" & rst!caseID & """")
    Set qdf = Nothing
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, TempQueryDefName, OutPath & rst!caseID & ".xlsx"
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
DumpTempsByCaseToExcel = True
Exit Function

DumpTempsByCaseToExcel_Error:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Runtime error " & Err.Number
DumpTempsByCaseToExcel = False
End Function
```

Assumptions:

- Your [caseID] values are alphanumeric. If they are numeric then you'll have to fiddle with the quotes in the code that builds the WHERE clause.
- Your [caseID] values can be used as valid Windows filenames. If they contain characters that are not valid in Windows fimenames then you have to use something like the `Replace()` function to remove them or map them to something else.
- Your destination folder is empty, or at least does not already contain files with the same names as the ones you will be creating. The sample code as written *might* overwrite existing files.